# What settings are needed to make a FortiSwitch 148F communicate with an HP 5130 using SFP Transceivers?

Tags: networking, hp, sfp

I have a FortiSwitch 148F-FPOE that will not communicate with an HP 5130 Switch. I get link lights on the ForitSwitch but not the HP.
The HP 5130 has a Dell-branded SFP module and the FortiSwitch has a Axiom-branded 'for FortiSwitch' module.

Answer (score 0):

The HP 5130 was originally connecting to a Dell 6248.
To resolve the issue:

1. Replaced the Dell-branded SFP module in the HP 5130 with a Axiom-branded 'for FortiSwitch' module so I had the exact same module in the HP Switch and the FortiSwitch.
2. On the HP SFP Port set the Duplexing to "Full". I left the Speed set to 'Auto' as changing this setting had no effect.

With the above in place the HP link lit up and traffic could pass.

Comment: First of all, the SFP modules on either side need to support the very same PHY variant - e.g. 1000BASE-SX and 1000BASE-LX *won't* link.